# Deciding if Valid FOL Sentence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am doing a HW assignment for First Order Logic with english sentences and this is one of the questions. Not exactly sure of how to approach it and to answer it.

> Q1. [10]  Decide each sentence is valid (necessarily true).  Justify
>   your answer.
>
> 1)$(\exists x  (x = x)) \rightarrow (\forall y \exists z  (y = z))$
>
> 2) $\forall x (\mathrm{Smart}(x) \vee (x = x))$

I don't really know how to think about these questions, I feel like question one is saying that there exists for example a person x Therefore all of people y are the same as this one person z. Which I feel like it could be wrong.

I also feel like questions two is true but only because Person X is the same as Person X

Comment: I think your intuitions are right. In order to be a bit more rigorous, for the first, produce a model which falsifies it (any model with two or more elements will do) and, for the second, argue by contradiction: if it is false, a contradiction ensues, so it must be true.

Comment: "For every $y$ There is a $z$ such that $(y=z)$". What is your intuition about it ?

Comment: And about "There is an $x$ such that $(x=x)$" ? Which amounts to : "there is something that is equal to itself" ?

Comment: Actually, I read that wrong: I read the first one as saying "there is a y such that for every z (y = z)"! As it stands, I think you should think a bit more about the first one!

Comment: Also, I formatted the formulas using standard first-order notation. Let me know if I got anything wrong.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, so i guess the (for a y there exists a z that is (y = z)) would be true in that regards unless i am incorrect in that assumtion.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA which the first section of 1 is true because x = x which is itself thus it is true.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Therefore because both are true statements it would make the sentence true because (true if true) is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

For 1), the antecedent says "There is an $x$ such that $(x=x)$", that amounts to : "there is something that is equal to itself".

The standard interpretation of FOL uses non-empty domain, that means that it is always true that there is something, and thus that there is something that is equal to itself.

Regarding the consequent, it says "For every $y$ There is a $z$ such that $(y=z)$".

And also this is true, because for every object there is soemthing equal to it: at least the object itself.

*Conclusion*: both sub-formulas are always True, and "if True, than True", is True.

---

The same approach for 2) : "For every $x$, either $x$ is Smart [maybe it is smart, maybe not] or $x$ is equal to itself [for sure it is true, whatever $x$ is]".